# Automatically dismiss the "This post has been deleted" banner in triage review

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, triage, banner

I just got a spam audit from triage, and I passed the review. I split the votes (by clicking the score) then the banner appeared:

> This post has been deleted

The following is a screenshot that I took when I moved onto the **next** review:

> [image: this post has been deleted]

And I selected next, then this banner still appears. No matter how long I wait, It's still there, and I have to click on X to dismiss it. Can we have it automatically dismissed?

Comment: Hmm.. Can we have the X back? :D

Comment: I've been poking around in this queue and I believe that some related changes that we made to audits have fixed this particular behavior. Could you please let me know if you're still able to repro? Otherwise, I'll mark this as status-completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll take a look at this as part of the [review queue visual overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) currently in progress and make sure things are working as intended. Thanks for the report!

We'll post an update here once that's done.