# Some Stack Exchange assets do not load due to CORS errors for https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/* URLs

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, deleted-answers, user-interface

When performing [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/) reviews I often view the [vote count](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) on a post as a quick way to determine if the review task that I'm looking at is an audit. When it is an audit and the post has been deleted, e.g. in [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28168829), a banner appears, saying:

> This post has been deleted.

Until recently, the banner also had a *visible* button on the right hand side to dismiss it - but as of maybe a week ago (it's hard to pinpoint) the button has not been visible:

In dark mode:

> [image]

In light mode:

> [image]

Hovering over where I expect it to be, it becomes visible again, but that is... not ideal, given that the banner [does not automatically get dismissed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403730/1364007) when progressing onto the next review task:

In dark mode:

> [image]

In light mode:

> [image]

---

I'm not sure what the source *used to* look like (I don't make a point of inspecting pages that work) but currently the HTML for the button is

In light and dark mode:

```html
<button class="p8 s-btn grid grid__center fc-dark js-dismiss" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Dismiss">
  <svg class="svg-skeleton-element-during-loading m0"></svg>
</button>
```

Could this be fixed please?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this isn't site-wide, but I only have review privileges on Stack Overflow so can't test this elsewhere. A search on Meta Stack Exchange for this bug didn't yield any hits.

Comment: [Already reported on MSE; part  of a larger regression affecting all sorts of pop-ups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359862/close-button-is-no-longer-visible-in-toast-notifications-and-error-messages)

Comment: Aha! I was searching for the specific text, not the behaviour. Is it worth keeping this question around if it's a cross-site duplicate?

Comment: I don't see the point in deleting questions here because they're duplicates of questions on the global Meta. I just like to tie them together to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

SVG icons recently moved from `/img/svg-icons` to `/img/stacks-icons` and we overlooked updating the CORS policy along with it. The issue should be resolved now, though you might have to "empty cache and hard reload" in the Chrome parlance.

Answer (score 8):

As a user with > 10k reputation, I can't actually duplicate the *exact* issue which you are experiencing, because getting the score breakdown works fine on deleted posts for users with >10k reputation. In other words, that error is not produced, so I can't 100% verify that the following is the same problem. However, everywhere else where I've seen the issue, it has been affecting elements which are `<svg class="svg-skeleton-element-during-loading"></svg>`, as you show in your question.

### Overall issue: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is improperly configured on the server

The issue is that Stack Exchange's software uses those elements as a placeholder which is to be replaced by the results of an AJAX GET call. Unfortunately, that GET fails and the placeholder element is never replaced.

Starting on or before 2021-01-22 there has been a CORS problem for Stack Exchange assets which SE pages expect to fetch from `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/*`. The issue [does not appear to affect everyone](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=51431406#51431406), but it is affecting more people than just myself.

### One example problem: Flag and Close dialog breadcrumbs

The asset which I notice is missing the most is in the breadcrumbs for the flagging and close dialogs. Specifically, the asset `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg`, which is supposed to be a small right arrow used in the breadcrumbs. Without the asset, the close-dialog breadcrumbs look like:

[image]

If things were working properly, then you should see something like:

[image]

### Testing for yourself

You can test to see if there's a CORS issue for requests made from within your browser for these assets with the code in the following snippet:

```js
$.get('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg')
    .done(function (svgData) {
        $(document.body).append(`<p style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">It worked!</p><p>The SVG is:${svgData}</p><p>You do not have a CORS issue.</p>`);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR) {
        $(document.body).append(`<div><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;margin-right:2em;">Failed!</span>See the console for a record of the request.</div>`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In Firefox, if you are experiencing a CORS issue, then when you run the above snippet you will see an error in the console which looks like:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Chrome will also display a similar error in the console.

In addition, [this link](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg) is directly to the asset which the above snippet attempts to load. If you're experiencing a CORS issue, then this link will work correctly in its own tab to show the SVG text, but the snippet will show as "Failed".

Comment: I was not seeing this when we previously discussed it, but I repro it now (on the same machine where it was previously working). I haven't even updated my Chrome version since then (although it has been begging me to do so for a week or so now). Perhaps I had these assets cached or something, and that cache finally expired?

Comment: That's certainly possible. jQuery tries to do cache busting by sending a parameter in the URL's query string which is the epoch timestamp of the request, but it's quite possible that Chrome, or something else on your network, was caching it anyway, perhaps even intentionally defeating jQuery's default cache busting.

Comment: Interesting: running `Svg.Achievements()` or `StackExchange.helpers.showToast('This post has been deleted', { type: 'danger' });` (as mentioned in the question) on MSO or on MSE doesn't show an error because the SVGs are fetched from the same host (`meta.stackoverflow.com` and `meta.stackexchange.com` respectively). However, it fails on other sites.